# Showing that $x_k = x^\ast$ or $x_{k-1} = x^\ast$ means $x_{k+1} = x^\ast$ in the Secant Method where $x^\ast$ is a root

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-writing, numerical-methods

Showing that $x_k = x^\ast$ or $x_{k-1} = x^\ast$ means $x_{k+1} = x^\ast$ in the Secant Method where $x^\ast$ is a root. I know the secant method is defined as follows: $x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{\frac{f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})}{x_k-x_{k-1}}}$. But I am not sure how to apply the statements above to this iterative equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_n = x^*$ for any given $n$, then $f(x_n) = 0$ and $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1)}}{x_n - x_{n-1}}} = x_n - 0 = x^*$.  It follows, that $x_m = x^*$ for all $m \ge n$. Apply this to $n=k-1$ or $n=k$.